# Extract information from a row, based on two different columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
ID           Name            Age           Medal         Country
1            Dimitrios       10            Bronze        GRE
2            Oumar           30            NA            SEN
3            Toivo           25            Gold          FIN
```

What I would like to do is extract the information (name + age + country) of the youngest athlete that has won a medal (Bronze, Silver and Gold).

Is this possible? If so, could you please help me as to how I should do just that.

Comment: Use `which.min` i.e. `i1 <- !is.na(df1$Medal); df1[i1,][which.min(df1$Age[i1]), c("Name", "Age", "Country")]`

Comment: But wouldn't that just give me the minimum age, rather than minimum age of someone that has won a medal. For example, if the 10 year old had NA instead of Bronze, the next one would be 25 years and that's the one I would want to extract.

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the youngest athlete who won medal X for X in {bronze, silver, gold}, here's one way using `dplyr::`.

```
library(dplyr)

# make some fake data 
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:7, 
  Name = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"),
  Age = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40), 
  Medal = c("bronze","bronze","silver","silver","gold","gold",NA),
  Country = c("GRE","SEN","FIN","USA","GRE","USA","FIN"))

# get just the rows where the person is the youngest to win their medal type:
dat %>% group_by(Medal) %>% 
  filter(Age == min(Age)) %>% ungroup()

## output will look like this:
## 
##    ID Name   Age  Medal   Country
##     1  a      10  bronze  GRE    
##     3  c      20  silver  FIN    
##     5  e      30  gold    GRE    
##     7  g      40  NA      FIN
```

This will also return the youngest person with `NA` as their value in `$Medal`. To just get the info for the three medal winners and ignore `NA`s, just `filter()` the data first:

```
dat %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Medal)) %>% 
  group_by(Medal) %>% 
  filter(Age == min(Age)) %>% ungroup()
```

Or if you just want to get the info of the youngest person to ever win *any* medal, then you can just filter the data directly (i.e. without grouping by `$Medal` first):

```
dat %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Medal)) %>% 
  filter(Age == min(Age))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but for some reason I just get this: ## # A tibble: 0 x 15 

And this is followed by a list of all the columns, with no data being shown.

Comment: check that the column names are consistent and that age is encoded as numeric, etc. if you run it with the sample data i provided, you'll see how it works. then can adapt to your specific dataset :p

Comment: also if Age has missing values, then use min(Age, na.rm=TRUE) instead of just min(Age)

Comment: The missing values are currently listed as NA.

Comment: Also, when displaying the row, how would I only display certain columns, rather than all 15.